# Timer is not running more than 3 minutes in background

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, background-process

I am working on meditation app. In this app i have some musical content and some silent meditation section using timer. Timer is working fine when it is in foreground but it is running for only 3 min in background(when device is locked or user press home button to exit from the app). I am using swift4. What i have tried :

```
var timer: Timer!
var timeCounter : Int!
var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
var backgroundTask = BackgroundTask()

@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
    })

    backgroundTask.startBackgroundTask()

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let currentRunLoop = RunLoop.current
        let timeInterval = 1.0
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.timer.tolerance = timeInterval * 0.1
        currentRunLoop.add(self.timer, forMode: .commonModes)
        currentRunLoop.run()
    }
  }
}

 @objc func updateTimer () { 
    timeCounter = timeCounter - 1
    let minutes = Int(timeCounter) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(timeCounter) % 60

    print("timeCounter", timeCounter)
    if (timeCounter == 0){
        if self.timer != nil {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.timer = nil
            player.play()
        }
    }

    timeLabel.fadeTransition(0.4)
    timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02i:%02i",minutes,seconds)
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This isn't the approach you want. Timers don't run in the background. (And you should almost never call `runloop.run()`; that's a very advanced thing to do.) And you don't correctly end your background task when you're done (you only do it when you expire, which is not good practice.) The precise solution will depend on exactly what you're doing. You probably want to be a music app and make use of that to drive everything else. You may want to consider silent audio (it's somewhat bad for battery, but may be ideal for this user experience). You can also look at UserNotifications to time things.

Comment: Given what you've described so far, I think you really can build something very nice using the standard tools. NSTimer just isn't the right one, and it depends on exactly the user experience you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply @RobNapier.... How can i resolve this issue? Which best solution do you suggest for this condition. so i can play timer for long time when user locked the device screen.

Comment: Resolving this issue will depend a lot on exactly your use case; when you play audio and when you absolutely have to run code. What you've described could be done just by being a background app that plays silent audio when you want to be silent (and that would be the most straightforward). See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @RobNapier: Apple would not approve an App using this trick (if they find out): "Apps that play audio content in the background must play audible content and not silence."

Comment: If it's legitimately a block of silence in the middle of audio, that's not a trick, that's just silence. It's always been legal to play silent audio if the point is that the audio is in fact silent (for example, silence between tracks or playing *4'33"*). I agree that using this as a trick to stay awake is inappropriate, but that's not what we were discussing here. The reason I say it would be ideal for user experience is that you could correctly show yourself as "now playing," and mute other audio as expected (the opposite of what you do when tricking the system).

Comment: (Of course it is impossible to say that Apple would approve the usage. Apple can always object to anything for any reason or no reason, and often do.)

Answer (score 4):

In general you get limited time  from the OS to run in background. You can check and react to the background time left using:

```
UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining
```

If conditions are good (device is unlocked, battery full ...) you typically get about 160-180 seconds.

You find detailed information in [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

As you want to play audio, you can use "Plays Audio" background mode to not get cut by the OS:

[image: Capabilities]

Depending how you play audio, [configuring the AudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/ConfiguringAudioSettings/ConfiguringAudioSettings.html) might also improve things.

---

Edit:
How I understand now from your comment, you want your app to do something every 4 minutes. The only possiblility I see is to use the [BackgroundFetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) feature. This does not guarantee a fixed interval though.

Comment: thanks for reply.@Shallow....I have already done this and my music player is working but i want run timer in background where user select the time for their meditation. it may be 1hour or more. So my problem is the timer is not running more then 3 mins in background. How i can run this?

Comment: See my updated answer. It is not really possible. You could schedule notifications to remind the user, but she has to click the notification then to run the app.